# How to compare two Amazon RDS snapshots?

Tags: amazon-web-services, snapshot

I have Amazon RDS snapshot that is taken once every day.

I want to find only the changes that were made (needing only the delta). Is there any way to find the difference that was made to the snapshot?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only do two things with an Amazon RDS snapshot:

- Restore it to a new Amazon RDS database, *or*
- Export the database (or selected tables) to a parquet file in Amazon S3

See: [Announcing Amazon Relational Database Service (RDS) Snapshot Export to S3](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2020/01/announcing-amazon-relational-database-service-snapshot-export-to-s3/)

The "export to parquet" option would give you the ability to **query the files using Amazon Athena**. You could write an SQL query that does some fancy `OUTER JOIN` commands to find data that is in one export but not in the other.

An easier way to go about this might be to add a `modified_timestamp` field on the desired database tables with **a trigger to update the date whenever data is added/changed**. This means you could run a query against the database at any time and just ask for rows with a `modified_timestamp` since a particular time. (This capability will vary based upon the database engine you are using. I have done it in PostgreSQL, but you'd need to check if/how it is possible in other database engines.)